# SAMSUNG 850 EVO 250GB - TRIM, GC - recoverability of files

Tags: ssd, trim

Can't find this information anywhere - hoping someone will know.

What type of trim does this drive have enabled when trim is turned on? Is it DRAT? Does it zero out files once they've been deleted and what size files does it zero out? Say if I delete a 1kb or 2kb text file, does it trim it and zero out the data, or is it recoverable?

Would really appreciate it if someone with this model drive (MZ-75E250B/EU) with trim enabled can run a small test to see if small text files of about 1kb to 2kb in size can be recovered once deleted.

Very interested in how trim operates on this drive and how aggressive its trim and garbage collection features are - how quickly it securely erases deleted files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question with my two SSD from Samsung; 850 EVO & 960 PRO (both 2TB)

sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep -i trim (or something with sedutil on /dev/nvme0)
gave only;

- Data Set Management TRIM supported

and not, for example

- Deterministic read data after TRIM...

So I thing that TRIM itself is not forensic proof on these disks!

The question is what after GC?? (anyway you cannot assume that GC will occurs in deterministic time)